# Divide Underflow

Tags: computer-science, divide-by-zero, underflow

Why is a divide underflow only caused when the divisor is much smaller than the dividend,  shouldn't it occur anytime the denominator is close enough to zero regardless of the size of the dividend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://www.strw.leidenuniv.nl/docs/intel/f_ug/ieee_ovw.htm

> The underflow exception occurs if the rounded result has an exponent
>   that is too small to be represented using the floating-point format of
>   the result.

This implies that the error occurrs when the ratio of the dividend and divisor is small enough to exceed the precision of the floating point format, rather than any dependence on a specific value such as epsilon.

As the denominator approaches zero, assuming a non-zero numerator, the result of a division will approach infinity. As the numerator approaches zero, assuming a non-zero denominator, the result approaches zero. When this value gets small enough, an will occurr.

If the numerator and denominator are very close in value, even if they are very small, you can get a useful result, so a very small numerator does not necessarily cause an underflow.

**Example**:

In C#, epsilon is 1.401298E-45.

epsilon/epsilon == 1.0f

Even though the numerator is very, very small, the result is still a valid float.

Now, if you were to try something like this:

```
float max = 3.40282347E+38f;

/// underflow, denominator will be 0.0f
float denominator = epsilon / max;
```

`denominator` will have an order of 1e-83. Since 83 far exceeds the maximum single-precision float exponent, the value will be clamped to zero. This is where the underflow occurrs.

```
/// generates a divide-by-zero error.
float result = 10 / denominator;
```

This generates a divide-by-zero instead of infinity, because the intermediate result, stored in `denominator`, is first clamped to 0 before being used in the second operation.

Whether you get an underflow or a divide-by zero can depend on the compiler, your use and order of parenthisis, etc.

For instance, again in C#:

```
10f / float.Epsilon / float.MaxValue
```

as well as

```
(10f / float.Epsilon) / float.MaxValue
```

gives 20971522.0f.

However, the mathematically equivelant expression:

```
10f / (float.Epsilon / float.MaxValue)
```

gives Infinity.

Comment: I think that I am still missing something.  Using numbers, wouldn't the following be true:  Assuming .001 is beyond the range and it = 0;    1/.001 = 1/0 = divide by zero, .001/.001 = 0/0 = divide by zero, .01/.001 = .01/0 = divide by zero.  What's the difference?

Comment: 1/0.001 == 1000; as the denominator shrinks, the result approaches infinity, not zero. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the question?

Comment: It's more likely that I'm not understanding something about divide underflow.  I'm assuming that a computer can't handle .001 and will round it down to 0 ie. .001=0, therefore if I try and divide 1/.001, since the computer sees .001 as 0, it's the same as dividing 1/0 which will be an error (no matter what the numerator is).  Is that not true?

Comment: I think that I'm starting to get it.  The examples really help.  Just to clarify, this is the second round of divisions, correct?  Meaning the whole thing looks like 10/(epsilon/max) == divide underflow == divide by zero.

Comment: @David If you pass in a non-zero value, such as 0.001, that value will be used in the immediate, two-term calculation. Since the divisor is 0.001, you won't get a divide-by-zero, since it's not zero. THAT result may be clamped to zero, causing an underflow, and if that zero is then used as a divisor, you'll get a divide-by-zero error. However, dividing by epsilon (0.001 in your example) should never immediately cause a divide-by-zero error.

Comment: @David yes, that sounds correct. The difference is in which order the operations are executed. If an intermediate result exceeds the allowed precision, you get errors. Otherwise, not.